# TypeError: _firebase_config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.db.collection is not a function firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**CODE IN WHICH ERROR CAME:**

```
const user = db.collection("users").doc(`${match.params.id}`).get();
```

**ERROR:**

```
TypeError: _firebase_config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.db.collection is not a function
```

This is the `firebase-config.js` :

```
 // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxx",
   authDomain: "xxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
   projectId: "PROJECT-ID",
   storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
   messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxx",
   appId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
   measurementId: "xxxxxxxxx",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);
export { analytics, auth, db };
```

**TRIES**:

Reinstall Firebase, Nopes
Reinstall all modules ( Delete node_modules folder and npm install ), Nopes

Comment: It is a normal firebase app, not firebase admin, I am using Firebase 9.0.2, so the syntax is different + I am not using real-time database I am using Firestore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Firebase Modular or `9.0.0` and later version, you should use the new implementation in the query, [for example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#example_2_refactoring_a_function):

**BEFORE: version 9 `compat` or version 8 and below**

```js
import "firebase/compat/firestore"

const db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection("cities").where("capital", "==", true)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

**AFTER: version 9 modular**

```js
import { getFirestore, collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

const q = query(collection(db, "cities"), where("capital", "==", true));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

In your case, it should be:

```js
const docRef = doc(db, "users", `${match.params.id}`);
const user = await getDoc(docRef);
```

Comment: Is the following correct: `const user = auth.currentUser;
    const userRef = doc(db, "users", `${user.uid}`);
    const userSnapshot = await getDoc(userRef);
    await setDoc(userSnapshot, {
      name: user.displayName,
      email: user.email,
      photoURL: user.photoURL,
      uid: user.uid,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      updatedAt: new Date(),
      role: "USER",
    });`

Comment: I get the following error: `FirebaseError: Expected type 'Ia', but it was: a custom Cu object`

Comment: @HridayaAgrawal remove `const userSnapshot = await getDoc(userRef);` and replace the `setDoc(userSnapshot` to `setDoc(userRef`.