# firebase database _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.database) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use Database beside Firestore, the Firetore db works well, but I keep getting errors whenEver I am trying to use the Realtime-Database

My firebase config:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "@firebase/firestore"
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxx",
  databaseURL: "xxxx",
  projectId: "xxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
  appId: "xxxx",
  measurementId: "xxxx"
};

 const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

 export const db = getFirestore(app)
 export const database = getDatabase(app);
```

my React Component:

```
import { database } from '../../firebase'

export const Subscribers = () => {
  const [rows] = React.useState([]);
  const [subscribers, setSubscribers] = React.useState(rows);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const usersRef = database().ref("users");
      console.log(usersRef)
      usersRef.on("value", snapshot => {
        const usersData = snapshot.val();
        setSubscribers(usersData);
      });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

.. .
```

my Firebase SDK

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.17.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
  },
```

I am getting this error while trying to use Real-time firebase database

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (0 , _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.database) is not a function
```

would appreaciate any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: \_firebase\_config\_\_WEBPACK\_IMPORTED\_MODULE\_1\_\_.db.collection is not a function firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69893409/typeerror-firebase-config-webpack-imported-module-1-db-collection-is-not-a)